# Make WooCommerce thumbnail images as bigger than main product image

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, thumbnails, storefront

I am using Woocommerce 4.2.0 and a child theme of Storefront. In the product page, I'd like to make the thumbnails images as big as the main image (692 pixels).

I have this in my functions.php:

```
/**
 * Modify image width theme support.
 */
function iconic_modify_theme_support() {
    $theme_support = get_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
    $theme_support = is_array( $theme_support ) ? $theme_support[0] : array();

    
    $theme_support['single_image_width'] = 692;
    // $theme_support['thumbnail_image_width'] = 324;

    remove_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce', $theme_support );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'iconic_modify_theme_support', 100 );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** - The following will dynamically:

- Disable flex slider
- Disable Zoom feature
- Set gallery thumbnail images size to the same size than main product image

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_flexslider_enabled', '__return_false' ); // Disable slider

add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_zoom_enabled', '__return_false' ); // Disable zoom

// Set gallery thumbnails size from single product main image size
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size', 'filter_gallery_thumbnail_size' );
function filter_gallery_thumbnail_size( $indexed_size ){
    // Get single product main image size
    $indexed_size = wc_get_image_size( 'woocommerce_thumbnail' );

    return array( $indexed_size['width'], $indexed_size['height'] );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

[image]

Comment: It's not working for me for now. I had the following in my functions.php, is that obsolete ? `/*Remove the slider for the product page images */
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_hemen_theme_support', 100 );
function remove_hemen_theme_support() {
 remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
 remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
 remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
}
`

Comment: I also have this : `function iconic_modify_theme_support() {
 $theme_support = get_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
 $theme_support = is_array( $theme_support ) ? $theme_support[0] : array();

 
 $theme_support['single_image_width'] = 692;
 // $theme_support['thumbnail_image_width'] = 324;

 remove_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
 add_theme_support( 'woocommerce', $theme_support );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'iconic_modify_theme_support', 100 );`